# How to use null as condition in 'if then else' statement in SAS?

Tags: sas

The logic is : If variable X is null, then output to dataset DATA.
But 'is null' can't be used in 'if' statement in SAS. How can I realize the logic in SAS?

Comment: There is no null in SAS its called Missing Value

Comment: There is a null value for numerical variables, not for character variables. I will add some explanation to my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is different in a data step than in sql;
*(This is because SAS is older than SQL)*

### The most correct answer

```
data FILTERED;
   set UNFILTERED;
   if missing(X) then output;
run;
```

### Alternatives

#### The shorthand

You can also use `if missing(X);`, a short hand for `if not missing(X) then delete;`.

#### The where clause

See the answer given by user "itsMeInMiami" and my response

#### Using literals

In SAS Character variables can't assume a special value to indicate they are missing `if missing(MyCharVar)` is actually a shorthand for `if MyCharVar = ''`.

Numeric variables, however can assume assume different "`null`" values, [read more here](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p175x77t7k6kggn1io94yedqagl3.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).

In practice, only one is used, and it has a literal `.`:

- it is the initial value of a numeric variable before it is assigned
- it is the result of a division by zero
- it is the result of calculations on missing variables
- it is the result of an outer join if there is no observation on the table the value should come from

So usually `if missing(MyNumVar)` is actually a shorthand for `if MyNumVar= .`, but you might run into a situation where a nerd has been fiddling with the other special values to indicated why a value is actually missing and `if MyNumVar= .` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Dirk Horsten's answer is right on target.  Another option, which may be faster, is:

```
data FILTERED;
   set UNFILTERED;
   where missing(X);
run;
```

The data step `where` syntax is close to a SQL `where` clause.  That is, it works on variables that already exist in the dataset (not those calculated as part of the data step processing).  If the SAS dataset is indexed, on the variables referenced in the `where` statement, you can frequently get faster performance.

Comment: In fact, even if `UNFILTERED` is not indexed or sorted on `X`, this solution is slightly faster, because the `where` clause is applied before the "program data vector" is created and `if` after. (https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2013/10/25/do-you-understand-the-program-data-vector/)

Comment: Nod.  I find it usually takes me more time to figure out if the code will be faster than than the increase in speed.  :)  If you are dealing with HUGE data it can help because as Dirk said, it saves SAS from having to load all the data into memory.

Comment: Indeed: if your source is a database, you even don't get irrelevant data out of the database with a `where` clause. _( Why don't you integrate our useful thoughts in your answer? It would be more convenient for future readers.)_